# Could not connect to the Gradle daemon in Flutter and Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

I just set up Android Studio and kept on trying to run a simple Flutter project but it keeps failing. I've already done all of the suggested environment variable path solution but it is still not working.

[image]
[image]

However, I get these errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not connect to the Gradle daemon.
Daemon uid: 172214b8-f7ea-4f3d-8ab7-c713e0d9b3a9 with diagnostics:
Daemon pid: 15560
  log file: C:\Users\George\.gradle\daemon\6.7\daemon-15560.out.log
----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-15560.out.log -----
2021-04-09T22:42:29.554+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Advertised daemon context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=172214b8-f7ea-4f3d-8ab7-c713e0d9b3a9,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\George\.gradle\daemon,pid=15560,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
2021-04-09T22:42:29.555+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Storing daemon address: [bae42ebf-f3ca-4a19-82c4-edb1b3ba7f99 port:52911, addresses:[0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0]], context: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=172214b8-f7ea-4f3d-8ab7-c713e0d9b3a9,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\George\.gradle\daemon,pid=15560,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
2021-04-09T22:42:29.561+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:29.563+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:29.566+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:29.567+0800 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] Daemon server started.
2021-04-09T22:42:29.567+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication] Completed writing the daemon greeting. Closing streams...
2021-04-09T22:42:29.571+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] stopOnExpiration() called on daemon
2021-04-09T22:42:29.572+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] awaitExpiration() called on daemon
2021-04-09T22:42:29.572+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is running. Sleeping until state changes.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.581+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.582+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.584+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.585+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.586+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.586+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.588+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.591+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] The file lock is held by a different Gradle process (pid: 4648, lockId: 2926288451081611781). Pinged owner at port 62685
2021-04-09T22:42:39.591+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2021-04-09T22:42:39.596+0800 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
----- End of the daemon log -----


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```